# CanvasJS - Dynamic chart without setInteval()

Tags: canvasjs

Here is the original example code :
http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/

I need to update the value without setInterval(), I mean whenever the yAxis got a value somewhere, then it will plot automatically without time delay. One more thing, I dont’t want to shift the graph while the value reach datalength, when it reach the maximum datalength, clear all the old plotted data, go back to 0 point and plot again.

Thank you for your support !

[canvasjs](/questions/tagged/canvasjs)

Answer (score 0):

Gia Huy,

You can remove dps.shift from the example to avoid shifting. Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/kud2qya2/).

And you can remove setInterval to avoid update of charge based on time-basis and you can manually push y-value to dataPoints and render chart whenever you get y-value.

`setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);`

Remove setInterval and push y-Value to dataPoints when you encounter it.

`dps.push({y: yValue});
 chart.render();`

and render the chart.